# Predicate to find an edge in Java

Tags: java, gremlin, janusgraph

The following returns an edge in Gremlin console:

```
g.V(196768).outE('E_ROLE_PERMISSION').where(otherV().hasId(213032))
```

In java the this results in `Method otherV() is undefined`. 
I am not able to find a Java example with a similar predicate.
**Can anyone advise how to find a single edge in Java**?

Environment Janusgraph 0.3.1, Gremlin Driver 3.3.3., Tinkergraph 3.3.3, remote driver with GryoMessageSerializerV3d0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Gremlin is perfectly valid. I'm guessing that you didn't static import `__.otherV()`:

```
import static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.__.*
```

http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#java-imports